# Why did Scythe Master put lube on Ein?

Tags: requiem-for-the-phantom

In *Requiem for the Phantom* (episode 3, ~6:30), the Scythe Master puts some kind of oil or lube on Ein's body. Why would he put lube on her body?

Comment: What scene and episode are you referring to?

Comment: i believe it was episode 3

Comment: It seems to me like he was varnishing her.

Answer (score 2):

It is symbolic.  In this scene, he is cleaning his weapons.  In Gusseppie's mind, Ein is not human, she is a weapon.  An inanimate object, and in the same way he cares for is ruger, he cares for Ein.  While I don't think he was literally rubbing her down in weapons lubricant or copper solvent, I believe the intent was the same.

Comment: He... actually was putting gun oil on her body. - source the anime and the 2001 copy of the original visual novel the anime was based off of that I own. Edit: Either way, he is still a egotistical pervert. *shudders*.